# Openlayers Remove Polygon Selectability

Tags: selection, polygon, openlayers, geometry

I am working with OpenLayers 2.13.1 and am adding a circle on the map created as a polygon (in orange color). Whenever you click on the circle, it gets selected and changes its color to dark blue. My question is:

- How am I going to prevent the polygon from changing its color to dark blue?     I mean, is there a way to make the polygon unselectable?

Comment: Please post your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved today, going through my code again, and you want to know what I was doing wrong? Stay tuned and watch the next episode!
Just kidding: I added the circle vector to the same layer I did add my features, what resulted in the selectability of my circle, **because**(!) I had a selectFeature connected to it. The solution to my problem was to use a new layer for the circle being drawn and to add the circle into that new layer.

**Note:** It's important to add the new layer **before** the feature layer in your code.